# Polynomial interpolation

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I need to find the polynomial of degree $3$ with respect to these conditions:
$$\begin{cases} p(0) = 1\\
 p(1) = -1\\   
 p'(0) = 1\\   
 p''(0) = 0
\end{cases}$$
How do I deal with the condition on the second derivative?

Comment: If you're really stuck, start with a generic 3rd degree polynomial and see what conditions you get on the coefficients. You'll see there's lots of simplification.

Comment: OK thans, I'll try that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally speaking, consider the cubic polynomial as $$p(x)=a x^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ for which the first and second derivatives are given by $$p'(x)=3a x^2+2bx+c$$ $$p''(x)=6ax+2b $$and now apply the conditions in the order they are given in the post. So,$$p(0)=d=1$$ $$p(1)=a+b+c+d=-1$$ $$p'(0)=c=1$$ $$p''(0)=2b=0$$ So, you have four simple equations to solve for $a,b,c,d$ from which $b=0$, $c=1$, $d=1$, $a=-3$.

Just to make the problem more general, suppose that instead you were given the conditions $p(0)=\alpha$, $p(1)=\beta$, $p'(0)=\gamma$, $p''(0)=\delta$, the same procedure would lead to $a=-\alpha +\beta -\gamma -\frac{\delta }{2}$, $b=\frac{\delta }{2}$, $c=\gamma$, $d=\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

The first, third and fourth constraints give:
$$ p(x) = 1+x+ax^3 $$
(just consider the RHS as a Taylor series in $x=0$), hence by plugging in the third constraint we get:
$$ p(x) = 1+x-3x^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\,{\rm p}\pars{x}
=\overbrace{\,{\rm p}\pars{0}}^{\ds{=}\ \dsc{1}}\ +\ 
\overbrace{\,{\rm p}'\pars{0}}^{\ds{=}\ \dsc{1}}\ x +\ \ \half\,\
\overbrace{\,{\rm p}''\pars{0}}^{\ds{=}\ \dsc{0}}\ x^{2}\ +\
{1 \over 6}\,\,{\rm p}'''\pars{0}x^{3}
$$

> $$
> \,{\rm p}\pars{x}
> =1 + x +  {1 \over 6}\,\,{\rm p}'''\pars{0}x^{3}
> $$

$$
\,{\rm p}\pars{1}=-1
=1 + 1 +  {1 \over 6}\,\,{\rm p}'''\pars{0}1^{3}
=2 + {1 \over 6}\,\,{\rm p}'''\pars{0}\quad\imp\quad\,{\rm p}'''\pars{0}=-18
$$

> $$\color{#66f}{\large\,{\rm p}\pars{x}}=\color{#66f}{\large 1 + x -  3x^{3}}
> $$